# What does this error mean on my Terminal when I try to command composer global require "laravel/installer"?

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I'm trying to install Laravel using composer command, which I already successfully installed.
Then, when I input $ composer global require "laravel/installer", I get the error message below that I don't understand.

Details:
MacBook Pro(Version: 10.15.3)
using Xampp

Thank you!

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v3.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].


Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Comment: The error message is _literally_ telling you what's wrong: `requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system` - You need to install and enable PHP's zip-extension

Answer (score 1):

It says that it requires zip extension

```
brew update
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3
```

It will install PHP 7.3.10 with the zip module. You can use PHP -v to check for the version, and PHP -m for the modules to check.

With respect to your errors Please do the following.

Add below to your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"
```

OR try adding the following in ~/.bashrc file

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: For a mac (OSX) using Xampp?

Comment: @Rwd Yes, I do. That's not Mamp.

Comment: @Shashank Shah Thank you very much for your answer. but It still doesn't work. The error message as below: Warning: php@7.3 is keg-only and must be linked with --force

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @Sanae I have again updated my answer please go through an answer.

Comment: @Shashank Shah Do I have to type like this? export PATH="$PATH:/Users/<~/.bashrc>/.composer/vendor/bin"

Comment: Do just like I have mentioned in the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already mentioned in the Laravel github repository [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30386)

As mentioned in the article. You can resolve this using below commands

```
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3 --force
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I got this message: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Have you reload the cli after executing this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm very new to programming, and don't understand what cli is..

Comment: CLI is command line interface means your terminal. Just close your terminal and reopen again and try your commands

Comment: I just tried to command again after reopening it, but I still get the same error message as below which I mentioned on the reply to Shashank Shah's.

Comment: try these commands brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3 --force

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207574/discussion-between-sehdev-and-sanae).